# HighCharts donut - how to individually adjust height of each external segment?

Tags: highcharts

I've been told this is impossible but I'm sure a HighCharts guru on here will prove otherwise!

I have created a two-level donut chart where there will always be 5 internal segments each with 6 external segments - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bytesize/a9qtmz38/29/)

The width of each external segment will always be the same, but I would like to individually adjust the height of each external segment to make it easy to see high vs low values.

Very crude diagram showing what I'm trying to do (I don't have enough points to use inline image):

[png image mock-up of different segment heights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXOnC.png)

Is this even possible with HighCharts?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bytesize/a9qtmz38/29/) - Code:

```
var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
    categories = [
        'A',
        'B',
        'C',
        'D',
        'E'
    ],
    data = [
        {
            y: 20,
            color: colors[1],
            drilldown: {
                name: 'O',
                categories: [
                    '1',
                    '2',
                    '3',
                    '4',
                    '5',
                    '6'
                ],
                data: [
                    2.5,
                    2.5,
                    2.5,
                    2.5,
                    2.5,
                    2.5
                ]
            }
        },
         {
            y: 20,
            color: colors[2],
            drilldown: {
                name: 'C',
                categories: [
                    '1',
                    '2',
                    '3',
                    '4',
                    '5',
                    '6'
                ],
                data: [
                    2.5,
                    2.5,
                    2.5,
                    2.5,
                    2.5,
                    2.5
                ]
            }
        },
                {
            y: 20,
            color: colors[3],
            drilldown: {
                name: 'E',
                categories: [
                    '1',
                    '2',
                    '3',
                    '4',
                    '5',
                    '6'
                ],
                data: [
                    2.5,
                    2.5,
                    2.5,
                    2.5,
                    2.5,
                    2.5
                ]
            }
        },
                {
            y: 20,
            color: colors[4],
            drilldown: {
                name: 'A',
                categories: [
                    '1',
                    '2',
                    '3',
                    '4',
                    '5',
                    '6'
                ],
                data: [
                    2.5,
                    2.5,
                    2.5,
                    2.5,
                    2.5,
                    2.5
                ]
            }
        },
                {
            y: 20,
            color: colors[5],
            drilldown: {
                name: 'N',
                categories: [
                    '1',
                    '2',
                    '3',
                    '4',
                    '5',
                    '6'
                ],
                data: [
                    2.5,
                    2.5,
                    2.5,
                    2.5,
                    2.5,
                    2.5
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    browserData = [],
    versionsData = [],
    i,
    j,
    dataLen = data.length,
    drillDataLen,
    brightness;


// Build the data arrays
for (i = 0; i < dataLen; i += 1) {

    // add browser data
    browserData.push({
        name: categories[i],
        y: data[i].y,
        color: data[i].color
    });

    // add version data
    drillDataLen = data[i].drilldown.data.length;
    for (j = 0; j < drillDataLen; j += 1) {
        brightness = 0.2 - (j / drillDataLen) / 5;
        versionsData.push({
            name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
            y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
            color: Highcharts.color(data[i].color).brighten(brightness).get()
        });
    }
}

// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            shadow: false,
            //center: ['50%', '50%'],
            innerSize: '55%'
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
        },
    series: [{
        name: 'Browsers',
        data: browserData,
        size: '60%',
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
            },
            color: '#ffffff',
            distance: -50
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Versions',
        data: versionsData,
        size: '80%',
        innerSize: '60%',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
            /*formatter: function () {
                // display only if larger than 1
                return this.y > 1 ? '<b>' + this.point.name + ':</b> ' +
                    this.y + '%' : null;
            }*/ 
        },
        id: 'versions',
    }],
    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                /*maxWidth: 1000*/
            },
            chartOptions: {
                series: [{
                }, {
                    id: 'versions',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using simply the `pie` series, you can change to the `variablepie`.
In this series, you have to specify the `z` value representing the height of each slice.
Remember to import the module into your scripts.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2b579pgz/